# find top ip address consuming juniper interface bandwidth

Tags: juniper

As you can see this interface is consuming 95% bandwidth for this interface.
I am trying to understand who is consuming the bandwith.
Is it some ip address or anything else.
And how can i find top bandwidth consuming ip addess in juniper interface?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a packet capture for the interface and analyze it. e.g.:

`monitor traffic interface ge-0/1/1 extensive write-file dump.pcap`

`write-file` is a hidden command. Run `file list` to view where it is, scp it off the machine. e.g.:

`scp user@192.168.0.1:/var/home/remote/dump.pcap .`

Open it up in Wireshark. Then open Statistics -> Conversations.